# how to a create bar chart in sillverlight reports

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0, charts, reporting

I am trying to create  bar chart on reports in silverlight(small bar chart) using Telerik chart controls.
I can find few links by googling : [Telerik](http://www.telerik.com/help/wpf/radchart-features-layout-mode.html), [other line](http://www.telerik.com/help/wpf/radchart-features-layout-mode.html), [another link](http://www.devcurry.com/2011/01/silverlight-4-chart-example.html).
But I need to display beside my reports.Can you provide some examples or links to tutorials?.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the Silverlight Toolkit is your best bet

http://silverlight.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Silverlight%20Toolkit%20Overview%20Part%202